# Input component > feeds Forms component - how to handle submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I am missing how to bring the input value out of the child component.

I have an *Input* component that I want to re-use, there I can see what happens `onChange`, and I see every change on the input field.

Then on the parent component, *Form*, where I use `<Input />`, I have the rest of the form with the Submit button. At this level, I want to handle `onSubmit`, but I cannot see/console the value of the input here. I can only see it from the child.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Input.js - here I **can** see the input value **onChange**

```
function Input(props) {
    const { label, name, value } = props;
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const updateForm = {...Form};
        console.log("change:", updateForm)
        updateForm[label] = event.target.value;
      }
    return (
        <label>
            {label}
            <input name={name} value={value} onChange={handleChange}></input>
        </label> 
    )
}

export { Input }
```

Forms.js - here I **cannot** get access to the input value and submit/handle it

```
function Form(props) {
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(Input.value);
    console.log(props.label.value)
    alert(`form is: ${event.target.input}`);
  }
      return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input label={props.label} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
      </>
    )
}
```

I have that structure because I am defining what I want in my Form on the main HomePage component:

```
  function Home() {
  return (
    <>
        .......
        <Section withForm label={["Name"]} {...homeObjFive}/>
        <Section withForm label={"Phone"} {...homeObjOne}/>
        .......

    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect case to use the `useRef` function from react.

In **Form.js**

```jsx
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
```

create a reference constant and pass it as a prop into the input component. and change the input value that is handled in the onSubmit function to the reference

Also in **Form.js** (changes are made to the submit function)

```jsx
function Form(props) {

  const { inputValue } = useRef(); // added
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(inputValue); // changed
    console.log(props.label.value)
    alert(`form is: ${event.target.input}`);
  }
      return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {/* added the inputValue prop to the input component */}
          <Input label={props.label} inputValue={inputValue} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
      </>
    )
}
```

and now inside of the Input component set the input elements reference to the inputValue prop. you will no longer need a onChange function as reacts `useRef` function is updated automatically

In **Input.js**

```jsx
function Input(props) {
    return (
        <label>
            {props.label}
            <input name={props.name} value={props.value} ref={props.inputValue}></input>
        </label> 
    )
}

export { Input }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a `form` with two inputs, `name` and `email` (these are the `id` props of the inputs). You can extract the form values like this:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) =>
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
    const name = data.get('name')
    const email = data.get('email')
    // do something with the data
  }
```

You can read more about `FormData` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).